# Volume benchark (software RAID) as opposed to drive benchmark? Bonus for free solutions

Tags: windows, software-raid, benchmark, disk-volume

If I want to test a single drive I can use HDtune, HDtach, etcetera to test one drive at a time. Unfortunately these tools don't help for testing software RAID. As long as Disk Management in windows sees the drives as separate items HDtune and friends offer to test the device not the volume.

With hardware RAID things are simpler as you can set up a volume equal to the array for benchmarking purposes before repartitioning.

Comment: What's the bonus? you're not offering bounty on this question?

Comment: The bonus is rhetorical. I'm asking this question for a matter of convenience. I can certainly run a number of benchmarks that I currently have access to. I'm looking for something more like HD Tune/HD tach in terms of showing the performance drop off at the slower end of a drive but smart enough to take into consideration that I have a software raid array going. It may be asking for something that doesn't exist or even isn't possible but that is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [IOzone](http://www.iozone.org/). It's flexible, open source, multiplatform and works with *files*. It might look a little complicated, but it's more than likely worth your while to spend a few minutes figuring it all out.

Among other things it will let you test scalability with multiple stream measurements, help you find the ideal chunk size, aswell as let you test with special options such as synchronous or direct I/O.

Answer (score 0):

One option you might want to look at is [Iometer](http://www.iometer.org/)